# Outgoing IP address of two IPv6 Docker containers must be the same

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, ipv6

I got a /64 IPv6 subnet on a server. I configured docker to use a default /80 part of it and I have an application consisting of 2 dependent containers. Those two containers are inside a abcd:1::/80 network. There is potentially a 100 instances of this application running.

The problem is that both containers need to have the same IP. At least I need to trick the application into thinking that. They consist of `app` and `monitor` right now `app` exposes two ports. One of which will be called by `monitor` the other one by external sources. `monitor` communicates with external sources and needs to do so with the same ip as `app`

Right now its configured as follow: `app` uses `abcd:1::2` and `monitor` uses `abcd:1::3` what I need to do is that the network bridge that is created via `docker network create` routes all traffic through a common ip. This ip can be any of the subnet. I think that the easiest way would be to route `abcd:1:3` to `abcd:1:2`. In the end calling

`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

from the containers must return the same value. Can this be done somehow with ip tables modifying the bridge after it was created? The current host system is debian.

Comment: Is this strictly for outgoing connections, or also for incoming connections? Why do you need a bridge specifically?

Comment: Well the bridge makes it easier to group them. The `monitor` container calls stuff on the `app` container. And each pair of `monitor` and `app` need their own ip. So the docker0 bridge is there anyways. As I need the IPs to be static too and consistent across restarts I need to configure that IP address for the containers. You can only do that if they are in a docker network but not if they use the default bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the best way to do this (maybe 'monitor' should instead proxy requests through 'app'), but most likely you can use regular ip6tables SNAT on the host, as in IPv4:

```
-A PREROUTING -s abcd:1::3 -j SNAT --to-source abcd:1::2
```

It might be possible to use use `NETMAP` to automate SNAT for all addresses:

```
-A PREROUTING -s abcd:1::/80 -j NETMAP --to ::2/::f
```

Comment: `ip6tables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Chain 'PREROUTING' does not exist` 
Also is this why persistent across reboots?